# Multiple Domains on a Static IP MS Exchange 2010 Server

Tags: exchange, domain

ive ran into quite a problem that won't seem to get solved.

My problem is as following - i hope you can give me some advice :

We're running a exchange server with lets say public ip 120.130.140.150.

The primary Domain for the exchange server would be **my-logistics.com** (example).
The **MX** mail record would be mail.my-logistics.com and point to **120.130.140.150** while our **A** Recrod for the website would point to **130.140.150.160**. The PTR (Reverse) record is set to

```
mail.my-logistics.com 120.130.140.150
120.130.140.150 mail.my-logistics.com
```

which would be perfectly fine.

Now, a second domain comes to take place, lets call it **my-container.com**. The MX record for the domain my-container.com would be set to 120.130.140.150 aswell cause its using the same mail server.

Now, when you're sending e-mails we're always getting an incorrect smtp-banner that doesn't match the PTR record. How would we be able to correctly send and receive authorized e-mails from my-container.com when 2 domains are using the same ip adress.

I've heard there is an SPF to use, but where do i enter it and in which form?

Hoping for some advice

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use one hostname and point the MX record for any and all domains to the one hostname.

The SPF record won't help in the PTR lookup.  The server needs to advertise itself as the hostname in the PTR record.

Comment: You mean like "public.my-logistics.com" set to the exchange ip (120.130.140.150) for the exchange server and then set records for mail.my-logistics.com to -> public.my-logistics.com and also mail.my-container.com to -> public.my-logistics.com